# email sends to .com emails not .co.uk

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have tried to use a simple contact us form for a registration form.

When the recipient email is `.com` I receive the email after about 30 seconds up to 10 minutes later which is fine for what I am after but if the email recipient is a `.co.uk` email I never receive the email I have tried on three emails with the `.co.uk` ending and I have also sent 10 emails in total to the `.co.uk` email addresses.

I tested this yesterday so I left it 24 hours to make sure they wasn't coming through late I have checked the junk and spam mail boxes and there is nothing blocking it for example a firewall or anti-virus any ideas would be much appreciated my code is below and yes I am aware of MysSql injection and also other techniques or with security this is not an issue and they will be sorted later on.

```
<h2>Feedback Form</h2>
<?php
// display form if user has not clicked submit
if (!isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
  ?>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
  Subject: <input type="text" name="subject"><br>
  Message: <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Feedback">
  </form>
  <?php 
  }
else
  // the user has submitted the form
  {
  // Check if the "subject" input field is filled out
  if (isset($_POST["subject"]))
    {
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    // message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
    // send mail
    mail("webmaster@example.co.uk",$subject,$message,"subject: $subject\n");
    echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: So you are e-mailing yourself after a user registers on a page? Why does it need to seem to originate from them? Can't you just include it as part of the body?

Comment: Not related but you're better off not re-declaring variables like so '$from = $_POST["from"];' and rather just doing 'mail("webmaster@example.com",$_POST["subject"],$_POST["message"],"From: ".$_POST["from"]."\n");'

Comment: I guess it is a blacklisting of the recieving mail server. Did you try different .co.uk hosters? A lot of large email providers will block emails from Servers with an IP from a dynamic IP-range. Also the setting of `From: ` header might be rejected if it does not include a valid email. All of this is depended on the receiving mail server and if it will accept mails with your headers from your sending mail-server. Take a look at the Mail source code received by the .com email address, maybe you will get a clou what is causing this.

Comment: MMM is correct, sending emails as “other people” via the `From` header can fail quite easily, some mail servers reject that (and it might depend on what exactly the from address is as well, I had such a case at work recently). If you want to be able to quickly _reply_ to them from the email you receive – then use the `Reply-To` header for that; for `From` only use an address that you _know_ your mail server is willing to send “from”, or leave it out completely so that he will use the configured default.

Comment: Examine mail server logs instead of your code.

Comment: @CBroe If he can send to an .com mail with custom `From: ` header the sending mail server is not likely to block the mails to .co.uk, but I totally agree that `Reply-To: ` is the better choice.

Comment: @Armin: The case I had at work recently was that the mail server refused to send mails with `@gmail.com` addresses as `From`, while quite happily accepting “everything else” … it worked for several other addresses no problem, and only after enabling error logging I found that out (it was the mail server we used for sending refusing to _send_ the mail in the first place, not the receiving party rejecting it). Colleague who implemented this some time ago didn’t bother much with error messages, what for …? :-)

Comment: @CBroe Taking this into consideration, try seding to .co.uk with the same `From: ` header used in the mail that was successfully sent to the .com recipient. @tripleteee got the best idea in my opinion.

Comment: @tripleee which server would I be checking the host that I am using or the recipients server ??

Comment: @Armin I have tested 3 different sets of results exactly the same in both of the examples and still the .com is not receiving the emails

Comment: @CBroe There won't be any communication from the sender and the receiver all that will be sent are the details that are input and then the person who receives this email will create an account for them using the information the only problem is at the moment the email account that will be used for the receiver of the emails has a .co.uk email address and everything has been setup using this email hence the reason trying to get the email to be sent to .co.uk

Comment: So is `webmaster@example.com` the part that gets changed to a `.co.uk` email address here (by you, manually)? Still, try _not_ to send the mail with an arbitrary sender address in the `From:` header – make that an address (a fixed one) that your server is “allowed” to send mails for, or as I already said, try leaving it out completely (then the server should use a default sender address it is configured with, and it should know best).

Comment: @CBroe yes the `webmaster@example.com` is the person who will receive the emails from this form, every time I try to remove the `from:` it causes a problem with the page edit the question with my current code. all I get is the title I don't get the message that should appear and I don't receive the emails either

Comment: The code does not reveal which mail server you are connecting to.  Probably your `php.ini` would be the place to check.  If you are on Unix, something like `/var/log/mail.log` would also be a good place to look.  On Wintendo DS, I refrain from commenting.

Comment: So did you try using the `From: ` that you used when successfully sending mails to the .com address? Did you try `<?php $from = "From: postmaster@{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}"` or `<?php $from = "From: webmaster@{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}"`? Are you sure you tested against different .co.uk mail hosters? What are your logs (@see tripleee) telling you?